# could not be able to send keys to the username box in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have tried many times with different xpath and asked in different forums but didn't got the solution. Waiting for your help.

```
package chromedriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Espncom {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Selenium softwares\\geckodriver-v0.19.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");

      WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
      driver.get("http://www.espn.com/");   
      driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log In")).click();

      //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Username or Email Address']")).sendKeys("cricket");
      driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div/div/section/section/form/section/div[1]/
      div/label/span[2]/input")).sendKeys("cricket");

   }
}
```

HTML Code for username or email address:

```
<input placeholder="Username or Email Address" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="on" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" ng-model="vm.username" ng-pattern="/^[^<&quot;>]*$/" ng-required="true" did-disable-validate="" ng-focus="vm.resetUsername()" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-touched" tabindex="0" required="required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="true" type="email">
```

Comment: In what forums couldn't you get help?  Just out of curiosity, cause as Auro mentioned after briefly inspecting the page you are trying to interact with, that it contains "frames".  Which need to be "switched" to in order for selenium to interact with it.

Answer (score 1):

In Espn site, when you click login then it opens a frame. you need to switch to frame and then you need to try finding the email or name textbox.
try with the below code and update back

```
  driver.switchTo().frame("disneyid-iframe");
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Username or Email address']")).sendKeys("cricket");
```

Comment: I used above code and this too. It didn't work. 
                   
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("disneyid-iframe"))); driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']")).click();
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys("cricket");

Comment: didn't work means, is there any error which you are getting, If so share me the error, so that i can help you.

Comment: getting this error                                                                                
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: 
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T16:15:26.402Z'